# How to select more than 2 matches?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having trouble thinking this one out.  Input is greatly appreciated.  Content is always changing, but here is an example of what I'm trying to do.

> STORY 1 (keywords: 5, 9, 17, 18, 25, 22)
>
> STORY 2 (keywords: 5, 25, 16, 19, 32)
>
> STORY 3 (keywords: 1, 9, 17)
>
> STORY 4 (keywords: 25, 22, 16, 3, 17)

Now, I'm querying based on STORY 1.  I'd like to output any stories that share >= 2 keywords with STORY 1.

For this example, my code should output:

> STORY 1
>
> STORY 2
>
> STORY 4

STORY 2 shares keywords 5, 25

STORY 4 shares keywords 25, 22, 17

STORY 3 is not outputted simply because it only shares 1 keyword with STORY 1

Any ideas?

Comment: It is not clear if you are asking how to model the tables or if the design of the tables can not change and you are looking for the query. If you already have the tables post definitions (sample data will get you correct answers fastest). If looking for help with modelling please state so.

Answer (score 1):

Something like (not tested)

```
SELECT k2.story_id
FROM keywords k1 
     JOIN keywords ks ON k1.keyword = k2.keyword AND k1.story_id < k2.story_id
GROUP BY 
     k1.story_id
WHERE 
     k1.story_id = @story_id
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

might work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it from SQL as Unreason showed, it is also very easy to do from PHP. Just make every Story an array of keywords and use [`array_intersect(story_1, story_n)`](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.array-intersect.php). You keep result arrays having more than two items.